# Active Storage with Exoscale S3 compatible object storage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

On a Rails 6 app, I need to use Active Storage with the [S3 compatible object storage provided by Exoscale](https://www.exoscale.com/object-storage/).

The first attempt has been with the following `storage.yml`

```
exo:
  service: S3
  endpoint: https://sos-bg-sof-1.exo.io/
  access_key_id: ENV['KEY']
  secret_access_key: ENV['SECRET']
  region: bg-sof-1
  bucket: testbucket
```

Which tries to store files at `https://testbucket.sos-bg-sof-1.exo.io/...`. However, on Exoscale SOS, the files are stored at `https://sos-bg-sof-1.exo.io/testbucket/...`.

So, I tried to update the configuration as follows

```
exo:
  service: S3
  endpoint: https://sos-bg-sof-1.exo.io/testbucket
  access_key_id: ENV['KEY']
  secret_access_key: ENV['SECRET']
  region: bg-sof-1
  bucket: ""
```

Which generates an error since bucket cannot be empty.

Is there a way to use Active Storage with URLs in the form or ``https://ENDPOINT/BUCKET/...`?

Answer (score 1):

In SOS (and on AWS S3 as well), https://sos-bg-sof-1.exo.io/testbucket/object1 is equivalent to https://testbucket.sos-bg-sof-1.exo.io/object1.

The former is called "path style" while the latter is called "virtual hosted", access through "path style" is now considered deprecated.

If you want to force the use of path style you can do so with the parameter `force_path_style` set to `true`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. If I well understand, the URL structure shouldn't be an issue. Correct?

Comment: Correct indeed, and path style still works on SOS